# Avoid plotting missing values in Seaborn

Tags: python, time-series, visualization, seaborn

**Problem**: I have timeseries data of several days and I use [sns.FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) function of Seaborn python library to plot this data in facet form. In several cases, I found that mentioned seaborn function plots consecutive missing values (`nan` values) between two readings with a continuous line. While as matplotlib shows missing values as a **gap**, which makes sense. A demo example is as

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
# create timeseries data for 3 days such that day two contains NaN values
time_duration1 = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=24,freq='H')
data1 = np.random.randn(len(time_duration1))
ds1 = pd.Series(data=data1,index=time_duration1)
time_duration2 = pd.date_range('1/2/2018',periods=24,freq='H')
data2 = [float('nan')]*len(time_duration2)
ds2 = pd.Series(data=data2,index=time_duration2)
time_duration3 = pd.date_range('1/3/2018', periods=24,freq='H')
data3 = np.random.randn(len(time_duration3))
ds3 = pd.Series(data=data3,index=time_duration3)
# combine all three days series and then convert series into pandas dataframe
DS = pd.concat([ds1,ds2,ds3])
DF = DS.to_frame()
DF.plot()
```

It results into following plot
[image]

Above Matplotlib plot shows missing values with a gap.
Now let us prepare same data for seaborn function as

```
DF['col'] = np.ones(DF.shape[0])# dummy column but required for facets
DF['timestamp'] =  DF.index
DF.columns = ['data_val','col','timestamp']
g =  sns.FacetGrid(DF,col='col',col_wrap=1,size=2.5)
g.map_dataframe(plt.plot,'timestamp','data_val')
```

[image]

See, how seaborn plot shows missing data with a line. How should I force seaborn to not plot `nan` values with such a line?

Note: This is a dummy example, and I need facet grid in any case to plot my data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`FacetGrid` by default removes `nan` from the data. The reason is that some functions inside seaborn would not work properly with nans (especially some of the statistical function, I'd say).

In order to keep the `nan` values in the data, use the `dropna=False` argument to `FacetGrid`:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(DF,... , dropna=False)
```

Comment: @EHB Yes, that is what the question asks for.